# SQLAlchemy 2.0 ORM filter show wrong type in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm to develop an app with SQLAlchemy 2.0.

When I attempt to query some table using ORM approach. Pycharm always display type error in the filter query.

For example, in the code snippet below:

```
    with Session(engine) as session:
        session.scalars(select(Albums.AlbumId).where(Albums.Id > user_last_sync_id))
                                                              ^^^ Show wrong type
```

Get the following message

```
Expected type 'ColumnElement[bool] | _HasClauseElement | SQLCoreOperations[bool] | ExpressionElementRole[bool] | () -> ColumnElement[bool] | LambdaElement'，, got 'bool' instead
```

[image]

Even though it indicates a type error, but scripts still be executed (And get correct data) without showing any error messages.

What could potentially be causing this issue in the code? Is there a way to make code more "correct" to let Pycharm not to display type error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyCharm assumes that expressions of the form `a > b` evaluate to `bool` when no other type information is available. Most likely, SQLAlchemy isn't providing rich enough type hints and/or stubfiles for PyCharm to correctly infer the type of that expression.

To resolve that warning, you can inform PyCharm about the true type of the expression using [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast):

```
.where(
    cast("ColumnElement[bool]", Albums.Id > user_last_sync_id)
)
```

Alternatively, you can suppress the warning by adding `# type: ignore` to the end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking to this exact problem and i came across this issue. Thanks for reporting it. @Brian61354270 is right, pycharm and mypy (if you have the plugin) will complain about type of the equal expression.

I just tried to install the stubs and the warning is just gone away

```
pip install sqlalchemy-stubs
```

Comment: Related background: [Stub Files](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#stub-files) from PEP 484 Type Hints

Comment: Note that it is [recommended](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/whatsnew_20.html#the-catch-all-stubs-must-be-uninstalled) that stubs packages be uninstalled when using SQLAlchemy 2.0.